# How to change the border color of CardView by first clicking and again change back to previous color on Second click Android?

Tags: android, xml, selector, cardview

How to do it using selector instead of changing background?

```
if(isSelected) {
                binding.cvStainMaster.setBcackgroundResource(R.drawable.boarder_blue_corner);
                binding.btnStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_button_primary);
                isSelected = false;
            }else{
                binding.cvStainMaster.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                binding.btnStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_with_corner);
                isSelected = true;
            }
```

I have done it by changing background. but I want it to do using selector

Comment: Do you want to change the border or the background?

Comment: @Zain boarder only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` there is no any property to change the border/stroke colour but you can achieve it using the `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` from [Material Design Library](https://material.io/components/cards/android#card) which is a subclass of `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` (`MaterialCardView extends CardView`).

To add the `MaterialCardView` in your project first you have to add the grandle depedency of Material Design Library pointing to the latest version like: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'` and your app Theme must inherit from `Theme.MaterialComponents.*`.

Now with `MaterialCardView` you can use the `app:strokeColor` attribute to set the stroke/border color pointing to a color selector to change the border color based on the card checked/unchecked state and the `app:strokeWidth` to set the stroke width. To activate the `android:state_checked=true/false` states you have to add also the attribute `android:checkable="true"` and with `app:checkedIconSize="0dp"` you can remove the default checked-stated icon. Below is an example usage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:cardForegroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:checkedIconSize="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:strokeWidth="4dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/card_border_selector"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

where the `@color/card_border_selector` is defined in the `res/color/card_border_selector.xml` like the below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

And programmatically every time you click on the `MaterialCardView` you have to change the state using the `materialCardView.setChecked()` function like the below example:

```
MaterialCardView materialCardView = findViewById(R.id.materialCardView);
materialCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        materialCardView.setChecked(!materialCardView.isChecked());
    }
});
```

**Result for `android:state_checked=false`:**

[image: unselected_state]

**Result for `android:state_checked=true`:**

[image: selected_state]

Comment: To remove the ripple effect from Material CardView I added 
  app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent" .  Thanks    @MariosP